# Полторы сотни - это сотни?

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные

Сотня - это просто сотня.

Две сотни - это уже сотни, потому что две.

А полторы сотни - это сотни? Ведь нельзя сказать что сотня одна, уже не одна, а больше. Но и пока что не две.

Или просто сотня с половиной, которые не относятся ни к сотне ни к сотням? Тогда к чему относятся?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, да?

Comment: Тут несколько вопросов. Все достойны оценки.

Comment: Не очень ясен вопрос. Например, если говоришь, что в доме проживает полторы сотни человек, то слово "сотни" это всего лишь склоненная форма слова "сотня", и множественного числа там нет.

Comment: @jsv А что насчёт этого? *У нас не хватает полутора **сотен** деталей.* *Не хватает четверти сотни.* Здесь так и остаётся, потому что там доля сотни. А полтора — это не доля сотни.

Comment: @oleedd Да, это хорошие примеры. Я не настолько компетентен. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь имеет место нестыковка логики и лингвистики, ведь люди говорят и развивают язык, как им удобно, а не как следует по логике.

С точки зрения логики — для множественного числа необходимы как минимум две единицы чего-то и целых единицы. 1,9 сотни — это не сотни, а **почти** две сотни.
Ведь 0,5 сотни — это не сотня, а полсотни либо ноль целых пять десятых сотни, то есть часть сотни.
В плане логики сотня с половиной [полторы] — это сотня (ведь в самой фразе это слово имеется), но с дополнительным количеством.

А вот в плане языка слово "сотни" в данном сочетании воспринимается как нечто множественное. Так сложилось. Не как одна (*полторы [части] одной сотни*), потому что тогда было бы *полторы карандаша*, а у нас *полтора карандаша*.
Это может быть связано с тем, что второй предмет задействован, ведь используется и первая сотня, и вторая, просто вторая не целиком.
*Четверть одной сотни* — здесь порядок. А вот *полторы одной сотни* — не логично, потому что у одной сотни нет полутора частей, есть только 1. Как следствие, *полторы одной сотни* не звучит.

*Полторы* — это как особый счёт, он используется равноправно с *один, два*. У *1,25* и *1,75* нет такого слова.

**Мысль в том, что сочетание "полторы сотни" не воспринимается как "полторы доли сотни". Оно звучит сопоставимо с "две сотни", а не с "треть сотни".**

И да, по правилам, числительные *два, оба, полтора, три, четыре* соединяются с существительным в форме ед. ч. (в форме такого числа, а не в таком числе непосредственно). Но это лишь грамматика, оно далеко от смысла, ведь никто не скажет, что две сотни — это одна, в какой форме бы там слово "сотня" ни стояло.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132408/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd----).

Answer (score 3):

1. Вряд ли нужно доказывать, что сочетания: «четверть сотни», «половина сотни», «три четверти сотни» обозначают долю от (кого?/чего?) одной сотни, то есть слово «сотни» здесь имеет форму родительного падежа единственного числа от исходного «сотня».
2. Если счет продолжить, имеем: «полторы сотни», «две/три/четыре сотни». Может показаться, что в этих примерах слово «сотни» - это множественное число от «сотня», но…

3… далее следуют: «пять сотен», «шесть/семь… сотен», где слово «сотен» (со всей очевидностью) являет собой форму мн.ч. от «сотня» и снова(!) в Р.п.

Чтобы понять, с какой формой слова мы имеем дело в п.2, возьмем для сравнения единицы счета, у которых формы Р.п., ед.ч. и Им.п., мн.ч. не совпадают добуквенно (как это имеет место для слов «сотни» и «тысячи»).
Например:

- полтора (два/три/четыре) миллиона (триллиона), но пять (шесть) миллионов (триллионов);
- полтора (два/три/четыре) часа (столетия), но пять (шесть) часов (столетий);
- полтора (два/три/четыре) шага (километра), но пять (шесть) шагов (километров);
- полтора (два/три/четыре) ведра (мешка/кулька), но пять (шесть) ведер (мешков, кульков).

Примеры показывают, что все единицы счета в количестве пять и более приобретают форму Р.п., мн.ч., а вот в диапазоне от полутора до четырех имеет место форма Р.п, ед.ч.

Итак, следует считать ошибочным предположение, что в сочетании «полторы-две сотни» слово «сотни» находится во множественном числе.

Comment: Два замечания. (1) Про ед.ч. всё верно, но это только в Им.п. или В.п.; в других падежах будет мн.ч. (2) полтора (два/три/четыре) часа / шага — это не совсем Р.п., а так называемая счётная форма (с другим ударением). Поддерживаю ответ с учётом этих замечаний.

Comment: Спасибо, grizzly, и за поддержку, и за комментарии. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0   Ваши замечания считаю существенными, поэтому привел ссылку...

Comment: В поддержку ответа: числительное полтора (полторы) во всех падежах, кроме именительного и винительного, сочетается с формой множественного числа последующего существительного. То есть в именительном (как в вопросе — полторы сотни; **полторы звезды́**, а не полторы звёзды!) и винительном существительное стоит в ед. числе. https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0/

Comment: Наглядно: https://books.google.ee/books?id=O7koCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8+%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=IpGvLd2--x&sig=ACfU3U2q88lj6p1alrBHel86P_d_FAxvJA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYgOLJpOn0AhVtsYsKHatGDqgQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5&f=false

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Вы, должно быть, вопрос не поняли. Полторы сотни — это несколько или одна, или ни то и ни другое? Как оно воспринимается? Процитирую автора вопроса: *Две сотни — **это уже сотни**, потому что две.* Вы же говорите, что там единственное число, противореча автору. Да без разницы, какая там форма, это не по теме, главное — что то несколько.

Answer (score 1):

«Сотни» в «полторы сотни» — не плюраль (мн. ч.), а именно генетив, (Р.п., родительный падеж): *полъ въторы* (т. е. второй) сотни.
https://lexicography.online/etymology/krylov/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

Лично меня в этом плане гораздо больше интересу**ю**т *полсотни*: сколько их, т. е. плюраль ли тут?

Comment: Речь о том, как сейчас (после "сращения и упрощения"), а не как было изначально.

Comment: Как было, так и есть: генетив, а не плюраль.

Comment: Сейчас не каждый догадается, что произошло от "пол второй". Этот смысл не закладывается. Так что нет, это не доказательство.

Comment: А чья-то там недогадливость — доказательство?))) Смысл именно таков, — почему нас должно волновать, в каждую ли голову он закладывается? Это проблема самих голов. Так что да, это доказательство.

Answer (score 0):

```
А полторы сотни - это сотни? Или просто сотня с половиной?
```

Если добавить прилагательное перед числительным, то ситуация немного проясняется:

```
Целых полторы сотни
Целые полторы сотни
```

В сочетаниях с пол- и полтора (полторы) возможны обе формы согласования (Грамота.ру).

Таким образом, в Вашем примере возможны оба варианта.

Comment: Не об этом вопрос. Автор не к месту второпях и сумбурно формулирует его: не правильно ли написано, а верно ли то, что *сотни* (в сочетании  *полторы сотни* — это не сотня. «Полторы сотни  это сотни?» — спрашивает он. Здесь *сотни* во мн. ч.?

Comment: Аргумент интересен, но проблема в том, что в "целые пол-яблока" тоже прилагательное в множественном.

Comment: Так это не проблема, а наоборот решение проблемы. Объявить все числительные (кроме единицы) - множественным. Пол-яблока лежали на столе.

Comment: "*Четверть яблока лежали на столе*" уже не скажешь.

Comment: А в чем разница между пол яблока и четверть яблока? Нету разницы.

Comment: "Пол-яблока" — одно слово, а "четверть яблока" — два. *Половина яблока лежала/лежало* (но не "лежали") *на столе.*

Comment: Окей. Что насчет "sqrt(2) яблока лежали на столе."

Comment: Жесть, ну вы даёте. Когда число заранее не известно, говорят "лежало" (*столько-то яблок лежало*).

Comment: Здесь число заранее известно. Просто подкрепите ссылкой запрет множественного числа и я успокоюсь.

Comment: Нет, нужно высчитать.

Comment: Нельзя сказать, что множественное здесь вообще нельзя (нет речи о запрете), просто нежелательно.

Answer (score 0):

Половинные числительные воспринимались двояким образом: как идиомы *полъ сема*, *полъ осма* (года) и после — как универбы *полсема*, *полосма* (году). В новом восприятии форма *полтора* свидетельствует о том, что итогом собственно фонетического изменения стало его переосмысление и утрата исконной связи с числительным *въторъ*. Ключевым моментом в данном преобразовании стало переразложение *полоу вътора* > *полоутора* > *полоу-тора* на фоне Р-Д-МП *полоу*, откуда после обобщения компонента *-тор*(*а*) возникла новая форма И-ВП *пол-тора*. [Из «Исторической грамматики древнерусского языка» том 4. (О.Жолобов. 2006)]

Счётное *один* в этой форме определяет её количественное значение **один и половина**, подобно *полъ сема* (*6 с половиной*) и *полосма* (*7 с половиной*). А в вашем случае, где единицей измерения значится сотня, *полторы* — это **одна и половина** сотни.